# How can we set the 'locale' in a prompt function

Tags: node.js, botframework

We can define message `locale` by sending an Activity object this way:

```
await step.context.sendActivity({
  text: 'Bonjour Bot Framework',
  locale: 'fr-FR'
});
```

However when sending a message using a prompt function, I couldn't access the locale in the activity object!

```
return await step.prompt(
  TEXT_PROMPT,
  text
);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to set the locale in a text prompt?

Comment: Exactly,

When using a Text prompt, the bot actually sends a message to the user.
So I am trying to set a 'locale' for that message based on the user's spoken language.

So I can handle that in the client application connected with Direct Line and make a few opertations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that simply we can pass an object to the prompt function, that contains the text and the locale.

```
let promptMessage = MessageFactory.text('Bonjour Bot Framework');
Object.assign(promptMessage, { locale: "fr-FR" });
return await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, {
  prompt: promptMessage,
  retryPrompt: {},
  validations: {}
}
```

Comment: That works. The TextPrompt isn't *really* meant to pass locale, since it's up to the developer to pass the appropriate string to prompt. That being said, I understand you likely want to pass it so the client app can do something with it. Be careful using `Object.assign` for it--it only works in this case because `locale` is in the Activity schema. Typically, you'd want to pass any custom data through `Activity.channelData`.